# How to remove an Azure AD B2C application's api permission by MSAL JAVA?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

I can grant an api permission by:

```
        OAuth2PermissionGrant ret = graphClient.oauth2PermissionGrants()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(oAuth2PermissionGrant);
    
        AppRoleAssignment ret = graphClient.servicePrincipals(principalId)
            .appRoleAssignments()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(appRoleAssignment);
```

But how can I revoke a permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access which was granted can be  revoked when that delegated permission grant is deleted. access tokens already in use will continue to be valid for their lifetime, but new access tokens will not be granted permissions.i.e;new ones are not generated..

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                                 .authenticationProvider( authProvider )
                                   .buildClient();

graphClient.oauth2PermissionGrants("l5eW7x0ga0-WDOntXzHateQDNpSH5-lPk9HjD3Sarjk")
    .buildRequest()
    .delete();
```

Please check [***Delete oAuth2PermissionGrant*** (a delegated permission grant) - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example) for details.

Similarly application roles can be deleted by using below code:

```
graphClient.users("{id}").appRoleAssignments("{id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .delete();
```

Please check [***Delete appRoleAssignment*** - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#examples)

But *`it is recommended`* to delete  app role assignments using the [**Delete appRoleAssignedTo**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delete-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0) method .

```
graphClient.servicePrincipals("{resource-SP-id}").appRoleAssignedTo("{appRoleAssignment-id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .delete();
```

**References:**
[Create oAuth2PermissionGrant (a delegated permission grant) - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)